# Rails - Select Model that matches two separate association conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have three models, `Model`, `ModelType`, and `ModelCategory`. They're connected to each other via an association table such as `ModelTypeRelationship` and `ModelCategoryRelationship`.

```
# app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_type_relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :model_category_relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :types, through: :model_type_relationships
  has_many :categories, through: :model_category_relationships
  ...
end
```

NOTE: `model1.type` would return an array of `ModelType` objects that are associated with `model1`. `models` may be associated with multiple `model_types` or `model_categories`.

I'd like to be able to select a random `Model` such that it is of `type1` and `category1`.

I was having some success selecting a `Model` of `type1`, but I got stuck after that. Here is my code for that selection:

```
ModelType.find_by_name("type1").models.find(:first, :order => "Random()")
```

NOTE: `model_type1.models` returns an array of `Model` objects of `type1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a scope to your ModelType and ModelCategory models:

```
scope :named, lambda { |name| where(arel_table[:name].eq(name)) }
```

You want to select "models", so it's natural to start the query from Model class instead:

```
Model.joins(:types).scoped.merge(ModelType.named("type1"))
```

And finally you can combine scopes on that way:

```
Model.joins(:types, :categories).scoped.merge(ModelType.named("type1"))
  .scoped.merge(ModelCategory.named("category1"))
```

Obs: I'm presuming that ModelType and ModelCategory have the attribute :name, so you can filter by that.

Comment: Worked perfectly - Thanks! For anyone interested, I found this helpful RailsCast when doing research on `lambda` and `arel_table[]`: http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: Also, for the random part, I just added the `find(:first, :order => "Random()")` mentioned in the original question.